# front page height way too long without explanation

Tags: html, css

My web page http://carmentoribio.com/ for some unexpected reason is too long. there's no element that can explain that, and I know I could "fix it", but I just want to find out whats making the page scrollable so far down.

Very weird.

Comment: Show your code please or a fiddle at least!

Comment: It's OK in Chrome. Nice site too.

Comment: You could set a max height on your parent container and add overflow hidden, if you know the heights of the diamonds, which I think you do. but this is not the best solution.

Comment: That's the thing I know I could fix it like that, but I'm trying to find the better way before that.
certainly, it's ok in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `position: relative;` from `.megadiamond`

Your elements are placed on the page and you pull them up by using `position` and a negative `top` value.

Try making them `position: absolute;` on this way they are moved to the top and dont affect the height of the page like before.

But a little bit of scrollbar stays there, because of the rotation of your element. There is a huge space wich it takes. Maybe you need to use some `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I think you're right. I'll make some changes and if no-one else has nothing to say, I'll check yours as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The 4th `<div class="megadiamond">` pushes page down. Check it in firebug.

Comment: Because it is positioned relatively, the space it naturally occupies is preserved even after it has been repositioned. As said above, hovering over that element in dev tools will highlight its original position right down to the bottom of the page (at least in Chrome). So a better approach would be to position those 'diamonds' absolutely, with the container positioned relatively.

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
       border-top: 1px solid #eee;
       text-align: center;
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 10;
       padding: 1em;
}
```

I changed your bottom value to 10, before it was 0. In chrome your footer content overlapped with body, this change avoids that. To avoid scrolling on page change your cage max height to an adjustable value.